# In Eclipse C/C++ IDE error opening library file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to run the program in Eclipse but I am getting the error

```
Error opening library file lib/ieclib.txt: No such file or directory
```

Even though this file is located in the project.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You may have to learn the concept of "current working directory" and realise that it does not necessarily coincide with "the directory where the executable lives" or "the top level directory of my project" or anything of the sort. Relative paths are relative to the current working directory. I apologise if you already know all this stuff.

Comment: I dont know exactly why this error is occurring because the same program run perfectly on my another system. I just moved to mac os. And i know its not related to OS but could you please give me a hint to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Check [this](https://codeyarns.com/2013/09/22/how-to-change-working-directory-in-eclipse-cdt/) first.

Comment: Thanks a lot Its working now.